# Bubble sorting talking more time than shaker sorting algo

Tags: sorting

I'm making a program for sorting arrays but when I run it the shaker sort took more time than the bubble sort and i can't figure out where is my logical error.

```
    public void bubble_sort_v2()// storing info where changes made
        {
            int handler_1;
            bool swaped = false;
            Console.WriteLine("\n                  Bubble Sorting v2 Algorithm \n");
            for (int lota = 0; lota < length_of_the_array.Length; lota++)
            {
                array_length = length_of_the_array[lota];
                algorithm = new int[array_length];
                Randomize_array(algorithm);
                Stopwatch time = Stopwatch.StartNew();
                for (int i = 0; i < algorithm.Length ; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = i; j < algorithm.Length - i - 1; j++)
                    {
                        if (algorithm[j] > algorithm[j + 1])
                        {
                            handler_1 = algorithm[j];
                            algorithm[j] = algorithm[j + 1];
                            algorithm[j + 1] = handler_1;
                            swaped = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
                check(algorithm);
                time.Stop();
                Console.WriteLine("\n    the time taken for sorting an array of length " + length_of_the_array[lota] + " is " + time.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds + " Millisecond \n");
                Array.Clear(algorithm, 0, array_length);
            }
        } 




 public void shaker_sort()
        {
            int handler_1, handler_2;
            bool swaped = false;
            Console.WriteLine("\n                  Bubble-Shaker Sorting Algorithm \n");
            for (int lota = 0; lota < length_of_the_array.Length; lota++)
            {
                array_length = length_of_the_array[lota];
                algorithm = new int[array_length];
                Randomize_array(algorithm);
                Stopwatch time = Stopwatch.StartNew();
                for (int i = 0; i < (algorithm.Length*0.5); i++)
                {
                    for (int j = i; j < algorithm.Length-i-1; j++)
                    {
                        if (algorithm[j]>algorithm[j+1])
                        {
                            handler_1 = algorithm[j];
                            algorithm[j] = algorithm[j + 1];
                            algorithm[j + 1] = handler_1;
                            swaped = true;
                        }
                    }
                    for (int j = algorithm.Length - 2 - i; j > i; j--)//going to the far left of the array and decrementing by 2 the first and the last 
                                                                      //sorted elements
                    {
                        if (algorithm[j] < algorithm[j - 1])
                        {
                            handler_2 = algorithm[j];
                            algorithm[j] = algorithm[j - 1];
                            algorithm[j - 1] = handler_2;
                            swaped = true;
                        }
                    }
                    if (!swaped)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                check(algorithm);
                time.Stop();
                Console.WriteLine("\n    the time taken for sorting an array of length " + length_of_the_array[lota] + " is " + time.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds + " Millisecond \n");
                Array.Clear(algorithm, 0, array_length);
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: include your code here rather then including a link

Comment: What did you expect? Both algrithms have an average case of O(n*n) both should perform roughly equal.

Comment: [Edit] your post to tag the language being used.